# Update table after expiry date/time with a Cron

Tags: php

I want a cron to run every hour that updates a table in my database.

I have a colum called "is_premium" and another that is "is_premium_until". If the time that is stored in "is_premium_until" has passed then, the "is_premium" changes from "Premium" to "Basic".

I'm struggling with the logic, can anyone help?

```
<?php

$servername = "*";
$dbusername = "*";
$dbpassword = "*";
$dbname = "*";

$con = mysqli_connect($servername, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);

    $query = "SELECT is_premium_until FROM users";
            
    $result = $con->query($query);
    
    $user = $result->fetch_assoc();
    
    if (strtotime($user["is_premium_until"]) <= time()) {
    
    $query2 = "UPDATE is_premium='Basic'";
    $query_run = mysqli_query($con, $query2);
}
else {
   Die
}

?>
```

Various ways of doing it, but I can't seem to get the logic in order.

Comment: Did you debug `$user`? `UPDATE is_premium='Basic'` will update the column for all users, is that intentional? Why `is_premium`? Why not only use `is_premium_until`? Why get all users data and not only those where `is_premium_until` is expired?

Comment: Oh yes, I realise this mistake now. No I only wish for the users were the time has expired to update.

Comment: This could be done in a single update query. Btw, `UPDATE is_premium='Basic'` is missing a table name, better check for errors there too

Comment: That was the issue, I've changed it to     $query2 = "UPDATE users SET is_premium='Basic'"; and it's works. Thank you :)

Comment: That would update for _all_ users, a where clause would help, something like `UPDATE users SET is_premium='Basic' WHERE is_premium_until < now()` (untested)

Comment: So it does, any suggestions?

Comment: You don't need the `select` mysql can do comparison. `UPDATE users set is_premium='Basic' where is_premium_until <= now()`. You should use error reporting. The driver would have told you error about missing table name

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is correct but, the UPDATION query seems to be not valid where it must be:

```
UPDATE users SET is_premium = 'Basic'
```

The previous Query will update the values of that column for all users because we do not provide the condition using the **where** clause:

```
UPDATE users SET is_premium = 'Basic' WHERE id = 1
```

> For more details read this [Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp).

Finally, you need to run this script periodically so, If you're a Windows user you can follow this [Tutorial](https://sqlbackupandftp.com/blog/how-to-schedule-a-script-via-windows-task-scheduler/) or use the [Cron](https://github.com/Cron/Cron) package.

> Here is another [Tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/managing-cron-jobs-with-php--net-19428t) for managing the Cron Jobs.